# convert selected columns of a pandas dataframe to list

Tags: python, pandas, tolist

I have a dataframe with several columns, among which 'value1' and 'value2':

```
   value1  value2    other
0      13       8    xxxxx
1      14       7    xxxxx
2      17       7    xxxxx
3      18       7    xxxxx
4      19       8    xxxxx
```

Currently I manually have to edit my_list values which are pairs of values into the format  below.

```
my_list = [[13,8],[14,7],[17,7],[18,7],[19,8]]
```

however I have been able to get the datainto a pandas dataframe in two columns called value1 and and value2 , so for example on my first row in pandas value1 = 13 and value2 = 8 etc.

Is there a way I can write something like tolist() that would output a list of the values in the above structure?

Comment: please provide more information, what is the output you expect (example) and what did you try to do so far (attach code)

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=["value1", "value2"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### short answer

Use the `tolist` method of the underlying numpy array: `df.values.tolist()`

or `df[['value1', 'value2']].values.tolist()` to select only some columns

##### details

You can convert from list to DataFrame and conversely:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [[13,8],[14,7],[17,7],[18,7],[19,8]]

# list to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['value1', 'value2'])

# dataframe to list
my_list = df.values.tolist()
```

`my_list`:

```
[[13,8],[14,7],[17,7],[18,7],[19,8]]
```

`df`:

```
   value1  value2
0      13       8
1      14       7
2      17       7
3      18       7
4      19       8
```

##### how to convert only some columns to list:

```
df[['value1', 'value2']].values.tolist()
```

Comment: This is amazing, my_list = df.values.tolist() is what I was after, i couldn't find that approach searching but that's brilliant,   is there a way you could specify only certain columns if the dataframe had more columns ... like by name

Comment: @RobPorter the `.values` is actually the underlying numpy array, check my updated answer for the subselection